# Fail to build the master branch of Chart.js

Tags: build, chart.js, rollupjs

I did git clone Chart.js from github and then `npx gulp build` failed. Error message was "`sourcemap` is not a supported option".

I'm using node v10.16.2 and npm 6.9.0.

I did

```
git clone https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js.git
cd Chart.js
npm install
npx gulp build
```

And I got

```
% npx gulp build
[11:19:05] Using gulpfile ~/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/gulpfile.js
[11:19:05] Starting 'build'...

src/index.js → dist/Chart.js...
created dist/Chart.js in 1.3s

src/index.js → dist/Chart.min.js...
    `sourcemap` is not a supported option

[!] (terser plugin) Error: `sourcemap` is not a supported option
DefaultsError: `sourcemap` is not a supported option
    at a.get (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/rollup-plugin-terser/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:463)
    at reportError (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js:75:11)
    at execMethod (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js:93:5)
    at process.on (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/jest-worker/build/child.js:40:7)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:832:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

[11:19:07] 'build' errored after 2.72 s
[11:19:07] Error: 1
    at formatError (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/format-error.js:21:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/log/events.js:33:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Gulp.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Object.error (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/createExtensions.js:61:10)
    at handler (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/now-and-later/lib/map.js:50:14)
    at f (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at f (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at tryCatch (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/async-done/index.js:24:15)
    at done (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/async-done/index.js:40:12)
    at onError (/home/ubuntu/tmp/chartjs-debug/Chart.js/node_modules/async-done/index.js:51:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
%
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I found the same error raised on travis. https://travis-ci.org/chartjs/Chart.js/builds/578433894 This problem occurs even in earlier revisions now. I have 10 some days old cloned repo which could be built successfully. However yesterday I cleaned npm cache and installed fresh modules then this failure is caused.

Comment: Your issue is probably related to gulp's handling of error messages in a callback. [Check this out for a little more context.](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/587)

Comment: @Kshitij thank you pointing out. that error message matter seems to have made difficult to see this chart.js issue. the issue was fixed with a dependeny correcting https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/commit/afbf6c301fdf546b71d196d7b79839f15501317c